# Book centered on beautiful blonde (nymph?) with green eyes

Tags: story-identification

I remember only bits and pieces because I read this as a tween. What I can remember is that the girl is created from a tree I think? A tree plays some part in her creation. And she might have blonde hair and green eyes. She is accompanied on her quest by a character personifying death. She also has a man with her at times as well as a gnome/dwarf who is her guardian. I also remember the beginning of the book follows a princess who falls in love with some kind of wood nymph or elf? And it ends badly. Sorry this is so vague. I have been trying to find this book for two years and started off only remember that death was a character...hopefully someone can help me out

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site, including tips on story identification questions.

Comment: When (year) did you read it?

Answer (score 5):

This sounds exactly like [***Child of the Grove***](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/338140.Child_of_the_Grove) (1988) by [Tanya Huff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanya_Huff_bibliography). It was followed by [The Last Wizard](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/338141.The_Last_Wizard) (1989).

> The world of Ardhan is slowly losing its magic, but one wizard remains--a master of evil bent on claiming lordship over the entire world. To stop him, the Elders send Crystal, the Child of the Grove, daughter of Power and the last-born wizard to walk the world. The final war is about to begin.

Due to the age of this book I found little in the way of descriptions, but these Elders include goddesses & nymphs. They work to halt the last (evil) wizard, and in the process of this the child of the grove (blond, green eyes) is born. One Elder, a dwarf, keeps an eye on her when she grows up as a princess in a mortal court. Once she grows up she catches the eye of the impersonation of Death.

References:
https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/338140.Child_of_the_Grove
https://www.sfsite.com/01b/wiz49.htm